# Passing i of a for loop to another function?

Tags: javascript, html, for-loop, indexing

Current bootcamp student here. [image: the element I'm innerTexting]Is there a way to pass the index of a for loop to another function? I am trying to fetch an api (which gives me a random cryptocurrency of an array) 4 times, then pass that data to another function which allows me to innerText the info to the html. Please let me know if I can add anymore info or clarify. Thanks in advance.

```
<div class="flex bg-transparent p-8 justify-between">
        <div class="bg-white rounded-3xl shadow-xl p-8 topleft">
          <div class="flex justify-between items-center mb-4">
            <div>
              <span class="font-bold text-green-500 padding-left">+ $726 (15%)</span><br />
              <span class="font-medium text-xs text-gray-500 flex justify-end">0.382 coin</span>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div>
            <h3 class="font-semibold text-sm text-gray-400" id="coin1name">BTC</h3>
            <h1 class="font-semibold text-xl text-gray-700" id="coin1price">Coin 1</h1>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="bg-white rounded-3xl shadow-xl p-8 topright">
          <div class="flex justify-between items-center mb-4">           
            <div>
              <span class="font-bold text-green-500 padding-left">+ $726 (15%)</span><br />
              <span class="font-medium text-xs text-gray-500 flex justify-end">0.382 coin</span>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div>
            <h3 class="font-semibold text-sm text-gray-400" id="coin2name">BTC</h3>
            <h1 class="font-semibold text-xl text-gray-700" id="coin2price">Coin 2</h1>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

```
function getRandomApi() {
  let randomApiUrl = `https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/blockchain/list?api_key=850252ca876085a93a414bceb298e21862313b438417b87364eb0fe9aab45e1c`;
  for (let i=1; i<5; i++) {
  fetch(randomApiUrl)
    .then((res) => {
      return res.json();
    })
    .then((data) => {
      console.log(data);
      updatePrice(data);
    });
  }
}

let updatePrice = function (randomData) {
  let keys = Object.keys(randomData.Data);
  console.log(Math.floor(Math.random() * keys.length));
  let propertyName = keys[Math.floor(Math.random() * keys.length)];
  console.log(propertyName);
  let symbolName = randomData.Data[propertyName].symbol;
  console.log(symbolName);
  fetch(
    `https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/price?fsym=${symbolName}&tsyms=USD`
  )
    .then((res) => {
      return res.json();
    })
    .then((data) => {
      console.log(data);
      document.querySelector("#coin" + i + "price").innerText = `$${data.USD}`;
      document.querySelector("#coin" + "name").innerText = symbolName;
    });
};
```

Comment: What result are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Are you trying to pass `i` into your `updatePrice` function? If so, you could replace `updatePrice(data);` with `updatePrice(data, i);` and define the function via `function (randomData, i) {`.

Comment: @edemaine this worked! thank you so much man I've been pulling my hair out for a while trying to figure this out

Comment: Great! I'll add as an answer. Enjoy your bootcamp!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To pass `i` into your `updatePrice` function:

- Modify the call from `updatePrice(data);` to `updatePrice(data, i);`
- Define the function with multiple parameters, like so: `function (randomData, i) {`